# hiding the last direction marker with Google maps api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markers, direction

I've calculated a route with the same begin and end point with the maps api.

Because the begin and end point are the same, the first marker is overlapped by the last marker. Now I want only the last marker removed.

I only know how to hide them all with:

```
directionsDisplay.suppressMarkers = true;
```

Is there a way to loop through the markers and remove the last one?

this is the code I use for the directions:

```
function calcRoute(waypts) {
    var start = waypts[0].location;
    var end = waypts[0].location;


       var request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        waypoints:waypts,
        optimizeWaypoints: true,
        provideRouteAlternatives:false,
        travelMode:google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
       };

directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

           directionsDisplay.suppressInfoWindows = true;
           directionsDisplay.suppressMarkers = true;
           directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

           console.log(status);

    }else{
         alert('SATUS:'+response.status);

    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

In initialise

```
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers: true});
```

then

```
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
var route = response.routes[0];
    var start =route.legs[0].start_location;
    var end =route.legs[0].end_location;
    addMarker(end);
```

addMarker function

```
    function addMarker(pos){
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: pos, 
  map: map, 
  icon: 'images/your image'

}
)
}
```

I have not tested this but you should get the idea