# How to Not Display End (B) Marker on Google Map Directions Service

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a map with a hard coded end point (Destination) like this

```
var end = "Coquitlam";
```

I am also getting the **start** value from users text input as:

```
var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
```

using Google Map Api documentation [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) I am able to get direction correctly but I need to remove the **MARKER B** icon from the overlay since I already positioned my own custom marker there!
Can you please let me know how I can do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [hiding the last direction marker with Google maps api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635805/hiding-the-last-direction-marker-with-google-maps-api)

Answer (score 0):

your_renderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({preserveViewport:0,draggable:1,suppressMarkers: 1});

OK?
But,you shuld put marker-A by yourself.

Comment: Hi tcltk-d, thanks for comment but to be honest, I got more confused by your hint! can you please let me know what do you mean by your_renderer = new ? and what is the Marker -A?

Answer (score 0):

The example is coded as :

```
function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(); // this is your_renderer
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523); // this is marker-A point
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum. I think you should integrate both of your answers into one and delete the other.